# what's the different between these two sql

Tags: sql, hive

SQL 1:

```
select  p.aaa, t.bbb
FROM  fdm.xxx  p
JOIN  gdm.yyy t
ON     p.id = t.id 
where p.dp='CUR';
```

SQL 2:

```
select  p.aaa, t.bbb
FROM  ( select * from fdm.xxx  p  where p.dp='CUR' ) p
JOIN  gdm.yyy t
ON     p.id = t.id  ;
```

table xxx is a partition table and partitioned by column dp.
our sql standard suggest write sql like SQL2, but when explain these two sql, SQL1 seems more optimize.
what's the different between these two sql? is SQL2 has better performance?

Comment: Can you add the explain plans?

Answer (score 0):

Functionally, they are exactly the same.

In almost all databases, they would have the same execution plans.  Exceptions are databases where subqueries are automatically materialized -- such as MySQL.

I believe that Hive will execute both the same.